# Not able to save my data in a file

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm developing an *application* where as user clicks on `log in`, I'm calling *API* for *Application* data(because *API* needs `user_id`) and taking that data in a `appDelegate` variable. After user logins and lands to home page there i'm trying to write that *App data* into a file but it's not happening.

Here is my code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/myagenda.json",documentsDirectory];
NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
appDelegate.myAgendaArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
appDelegate.myAgendaArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
if (!appDelegate.myAgendaArray) {
    appDelegate.myAgendaArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.myAgendaArray);
[appDelegate.myAgendaArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
appDelegate.myAgendaArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.myAgendaArray);
```

Comment: Why are you allocating "appDelegate.myAgendaArray" after you have written it in document directory path?

Comment: I'm trying to take the data from file at the same time. but I'lost my data from `appDelegate.myAgendaArray` before writing to file.

Comment: Does your file contains data(which you have save in document directory if so in which formate it is saved)?

Comment: Rather than storing data in file,it is advisable to store data in Database.
anyways,

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.txt"];
    NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"String to write"];
    [temp writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [temp release];

Comment: @CharanGiri: My file doesn't contain anything for now. I'm trying to write my `NSMutableArray` directly into file.

Comment: @V.D : It's not a string, It's an mutable array.

Comment: What is the return code of `writeToFile:`?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to load *.json file with `arrayWithContentsOfFile`? That method expects an XML or binary plist file.

JSON files must be read like this:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
appDelegate.myAgendaArray = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating your array too many times causes the loss of data.

Re-writing your code(removing unwanted lines):

```
appDelegate.myAgendaArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
if (!appDelegate.myAgendaArray) {
    appDelegate.myAgendaArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.myAgendaArray);
[appDelegate.myAgendaArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.myAgendaArray);
```

Also, one more point is that, your array seems empty. You haven't added any thing to array.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it's not empty i'm checking that before writing this piece of code.

Comment: means i have data in appDelegate.myAgendaArray variable before writing to file.

Comment: The logic in the code u posted: create an array from a file and then write same array to file. it will always be same, nothing is added or removed from array before writing. Is this the full code, or just sample code?

Comment: I'm trying to save an array directly to file but i just got to know that i need to convert that array into NSData. is it right?

Comment: The writeToFile:atomically: method on NSMutableArray only works if all of the elements of the array are property list objects (NSString, NSData, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects.).

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your path

Replace this:

```
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/myagenda.json",documentsDirectory];
```

With

```
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myagenda.json"];
```

**And convert your array to NSData then write to filePath.**

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to save an array directly to the file. You should use [appDelegate.myAgendaArray description] or first convert it into NSdata.